# how can i run build_native android project

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

i want to setup a cocos3d project for android but a message from DOS says "fail!"

> The Selected NDK toolchain version was 4.9 !
>   make.exe: *** D:\Tutorials: No such file or directory.  Stop.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:\Tutorials and Lessons# Programming Languages#Android Development\Android Game Development\Engines\Cocos2D\cocos2d-x-3.4... and so on to ..] fails!

i have tried with Cygwin and CMD on windows 7
what should i do ?

Comment: remove the spaces from your path ....

Comment: I removed the spaces and it worked thanks bro